# Python Program to Reverse Number Using Recursive Function problem

Tags: python, recursion

This code doesnt work for some reason but im not sure why

```
def rev(n):
    if not n:
         return 0 
    return rev(int(n/10))*10 + n%10
```

> rev(512)

> 152

but when i save it in a specific variable and pass it through the function, it works.
why does this happen? anyone can help me with it?

```
def rev(n,r=0):
    if not n:
        return r
    r = r*10 + n%10
    return rev(int(n/10),r)
```

> rev(512)

> 215

Comment: See this for a recursive solution without the extra parameter: [Python reverse integer using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407845)

Comment: Side note: you can use integer division `n // 10` instead of `int(n / 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use recursion to solve this problem, a possible way is to recursively compute the sum between each digit of `n`, multiplied by 10 to the power of `n`'s **order of magnitude** at each recursion.

```
from math import log10

def rev(n):
    if not n:
        return 0
    return int(n%10)*10**int(log10(n)) + rev(n//10)
```

As a side note, if you don't have to use recursion there are much simpler ways of doing this with `str` processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rev(n,r=0):
    if not n:
        return r
    r = r*10 + n%10
    return rev(int(n/10),r)

#the above code can reverse the number digit by digit,bringing it forward;

def rev(n):
    if not n:
         return 0 
    return rev(int(n/10))*10 + n%10
#this code will  do some other thing;
#once try for few examples;
#preferable 1234;
#you can get the differences of bith the algo
```